# How do we display a view in ExtJS using browser's console

Tags: google-chrome, extjs

Is there any way to display our view without creating any button clicks events in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Console view

**give your view xtype and id to the Viewport items and then paste the code into the console**

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype : 'panel',
        itemId : 'testingOverlay', 
        showAnimation : {
            type : 'popIn',
            duration : 250,
            easing : 'ease-out'
        },
        hideAnimation : {
            type : 'popOut',
            duration : 250,
            easing : 'ease-out'
        },

        height : '630px',
        width : '335px',
        left : '210px',
        top : '205px', 
        items :  [{
            xtype : 'viewXtype',
            id : 'viewId'
        }],


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use renderTo property, if you specify renderTo:Ext.getBody() it will render the content or replace Ext.getBody() with html element.

But in real applications you will need a viewport this is better than renderTo

[Fiddle Sample Code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lhp)

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
title:'Test Panel',
width:400,
height:500,
renderTo:Ext.getBody()
});
```